# Opencv Error on Ubuntu Webcam (Logitech C270) Capture -> HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

Tags: opencv, webcam, capture

this erorr message appears on running simple camera capture on Ubuntu with logitech C270 (OpenCV 2.4.2/C++):

> HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

and further:

> Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd1
>   Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd6
>   Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
>   Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0

I get frames but the values of frame width and height swapped when writing to a Mat object see below:

```
Mat frame;
videoCapture = new VideoCapture(camId);
if(!videoCapture->isOpened()) throw Exception();

cout << "Frame width: " << videoCapture->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) << endl;
cout << "Frame height: " << videoCapture->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) << endl;

(*videoCapture) >> frame;

cout << "Mat width: " << frame.rows << endl;
cout << "Mat height: " << frame.cols << endl;
```

Output:

```
Frame width: 640
Frame height: 480
Mat width: 480
Mat height: 640
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of an image is given by its number of columns. Your code should be

```
cout << "Mat width: " << frame.cols << endl;
cout << "Mat height: " << frame.rows << endl;
```

So there is no swap between width and height.

Comment: But I don't know how to get rid of the error messages you get. I get them too on my machine.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't feel like debugging the problem, and the frames from your webcam are being displayed without any issues, your option is to just shoot the messenger.  The instructions below work if you have built OpenCV from source, as opposed to installing pre-built binaries.

Start with `grep -R "Corrupt JPEG data" ~/src/opencv-2.4.4/` and go deeper into the rabbit hole until you find what you want.  In my case the culprit is at `opencv-2.4.4/thirdparty/libjpeg/jdmarker.c:908`:

```
  if (cinfo->marker->discarded_bytes != 0) {
    WARNMS2(cinfo, JWRN_EXTRANEOUS_DATA, cinfo->marker->discarded_bytes, c);
    cinfo->marker->discarded_bytes = 0;
  }
```

The `WARNMS2` macro is what's causing the error messages about extraneous data to be printed.  Just comment it out, rebuild OpenCV and carry on with your work.  I also have a C270, run Ubuntu 12.04, and experienced the same nagging error message until I did what I described above.

Answer (score 6):

About issue:

> Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd1 Corrupt JPEG
> data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd6 Corrupt JPEG data: 1
> extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0 Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous
> bytes before marker 0xd0

Looks like, the issue is in libjpeg library. For some unknown reason it works incorrect under OpenCV library. I tried to compile without support of JPEG and it solved this issue.

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D WITH_JPEG=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF  ..

You can find all details in my blog:

http://privateblog.by/linux/opencv-i-corrupt-jpeg-data-na-linux/

Comment: JDK on linux contains its own libjpeg. Now I think that during compilation this library is used instead of correct from linux. And it causes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would post this as a comment (not enough reputation), still, I got stuck here and the solution I found, though not elegant, was:

```
python my_app.py 2<&1 | grep -v "Corrupt JPEG data"
```

Note: To replicate normal python print statements behaviour I'm using `os.system(f'echo {my_string}')`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the output quickly and `grep -v Corrupt` does not work for somehow - like for me - you could also redirect stderr to nothing, e.g.

```
./my_app 2> /dev/null

python my_app.py 2> /dev/null
```

This will of course hide other error messages, too.